# How can I rewrite all requests except for one specific URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is my root path folder content :

```
/public
/src
/script
/etc
```

I succesfully managed to rewrite all request to /public folder with following code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

My issue is that I need to access /script/script.php from browser, and it is currently returning

```
NOT FOUND The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

I tried a lot of things that I founded on stackoverflow but I am really not at ease with Apache 2 .htaccess (but need to use it on a shared hosting)

Anybody know how achieve what I want to do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your .htaccess rules file in following manner. I have added a condition before your last RewriteRule since you want to access script.php so better put a proper condition before last rule.

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/script/script\.php/?\??\S*\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: You rock !!! Didn't thought it had to be place here, but make sense now. Thousand thanks to you <3

Comment: @ThibaudLafont, Your welcome, happy to help. Also I have made a small change in your 1st redirection rule to avoid any kind of query strings to be added(just in case), so you can test latest edited rules, cheers.